# What has Mamoru Hosoda directed at Toei that he isn't credited for?

Tags: anime-production, mamoru-hosoda

On [AnimeNewsNetwork](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/people.php?id=4068), Mamoru Hosada is credited for around thirty productions under various roles:

- *Alice SOS* (TV)
- *Ashita no Nadja* (TV)
- *Coo: Tooi Umi Kara Kita Coo* (movie)
- *Crying Freeman* (OAV)
- *Digimon Adventure* (TV)
- *Digimon Adventure: Bokura no War Game* (movie)
- *Digimon Adventure: Born of Koromon* (movie)
- *Digimon: The Movie* (U.S.)
- *Dragon Ball Movie 4: The Path to Power*
- *Dragon Ball Z* (TV)
- *Dragon Ball Z Movie 10: Broly - Second Coming*
- *Dragon Ball Z Movie 8: The Legendary Super Saiyan*
- *Galaxy Express 999: Eternal Fantasy* (movie)
- *(The) Girl Who Leapt Through Time* (movie)
- *Occult Academy* (TV)
- *Ojamajo Doremi DOKKAAN!* (TV)
- *Ōkami Kodomo no Ame to Yuki* (manga)
- *One Piece* (TV)
- *One Piece: Omatsuri Danshaku to Himitsu no Shima* (movie 6)
- *Sailor Moon Sailor Stars* (TV)
- *Sailor Moon SuperS Movie: Black Dream Hole*
- *Samurai Champloo* (TV)
- *Slam Dunk* (TV)
- *Slam Dunk: Hoero Basketman Tamashii! Hanamichi to Rukawa no Atsuki Natsu* (movie)
- *Slam Dunk: Shōhoku Saidai no Kiki! Moero Sakuragi Hanamichi* (movie)
- *Slam Dunk: Zenkoku Seiha da! Sakuragi Hanamichi* (movie)
- *Spiral* (TV)
- *Summer Wars* (manga, movie)
- *Superflat Monogram* (movie)
- *Voogie's Angel* (OAV)
- *Wolf Children* (movie)
- *Yu Yu Hakusho The Movie: Poltergeist Report*

However, I know he directed a few episodes of *Gegege no Kitaro* in the mid '90s and the CG short *Digimon Adventure 3D: Digimon Grandprix*. Which *Kitaro* episodes did he direct, and is there anything else he directed that ANN hasn't credited him for?

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the list of things that ANN does credit him for, to protect against link rot and make the question more self-contained.

Comment: Everything is answered here: [ja.wikipedia.org - 細田守](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%B4%B0%E7%94%B0%E5%AE%88#.E7.9B.A3.E7.9D.A3.E4.BD.9C.E5.93.81)